# How to deal with responsive design without using metatag viewport?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

My design works fine (it's a circle object with rotate functionality) with meta tag `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` but when I fit that design into any responsive template it won't work.

Reason I find out is that every responsive template e:g: bootstrap,foundation,skeleton etc. use metatag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

http://prefortune.com/rotate/bootstrap/

You can click on changeview link in responsive mode on above link it will change view and circle design will be fit properly but toggle menu will be loss. (On click I am removing content of viewport metatag content.)

Answer (score 1):

I just notice something interesting and want to share it, maybe it will help someone. In the site header section you should include first the bootstrap.css and only after that the bootstrap-responsive.css because obviously the responsive.css depends on the the bootstrap.css

Of course the meta tag should be also present.

```
 Error Code
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: It's fine.. but my question is different metatag viewport create a conflict with design... for that I need solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap you can try this.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
 <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting at line 315 in your HTML you have

```
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It looks to me that this path to jquery may not be correct, and as a result the bootstrap js isn't working, and this would cause a problem with the toggle menu.

This may not be the full answer to all your questions, but a good place to start.

Another issue I notice is that the source document for your iframe isn't responsive: http://prefortune.com/rotate/

If you view this on a narrow viewport the layout breaks, so this might need some attention as well. Iframes with responsive design can complicate your life and to begin you would need to add a viewport meta tag to this page as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David for your interest and answer to me.. but I have problem with metatag name viewport as it's conflict.

Comment: I would still start by adding jquery to your directory  prefortune.com/rotate/bootstrap/js/ ... fix one issue at a time :)

Comment: Thanks David, but issue not related with jquery it's related with metatag viewport. in given link look into responsive view and then click on change view link (I am removing metatag name='viewport') and that circle will be fit perfectly in screen but responsive layout of bootstrap will be mess-up.